# ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> to SQLite database android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, arraylist, hashmap

I have a database that has a table with 4 columns : ID, Contact(name), Phone, Message.

ID is auto incremented. 
Contact name and number comes from an  ArrayList> 
Message comes from an EditText.

I am have problems trying to create the part to bring in the  ArrayList> to the Database.

I have the part for the message but later I will need to either put that message in every slot? Or maybe not save it in the database but somewhere else.

Also, should I keep the contact name? or just the number since the number is what will be used to send the SMS message?

Thanks in advance! 
Below is my code.

Contacts.java - gets the contacts from the contact list and saves them in an ArrayList>

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.deptofpharmacology.test.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;


public class Contacts extends ActionBarActivity {
private static final int PICK_CONTACT = 1;
private static final String TAG = "The Goods: ";
DatabHelper myDb;

private static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getContacts = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

private static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data1 = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();



private static HashMap<String, String> contacts = new HashMap<String,String>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_contacts);
    myDb = new DatabHelper(this);
   // ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getD =  myDb.insertRecord();

}


/**
this is what's going to be used to transfer the Arraylist<HashMap> to the database
public void AddConPhon(){
    boolean isInserted = myDb.insertData(Contacts.this, );
}
**/
public void btnAddContacts_Click(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);
}

public void btnDone_Click(View view){
    Intent i = new Intent(Contacts.this, Message.class);
    startActivity(i);
}



@Override
public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (reqCode) {
        case (PICK_CONTACT):
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Uri contactData = data.getData();
                Cursor c = managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);
                if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                    String id =
                            c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

                    String hasPhone =
                            c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));

                    if (hasPhone.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                        Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = " + id,
                                null, null);
                        phones.moveToFirst();
                        String phn_no = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex("data1"));
                        String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.DISPLAY_NAME));

                            contacts.put(name, phn_no);

                            HashMap<String, String> h = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            h.put("name", name);
                            h.put("phone", phn_no);
                            data1.add(h);

                        Toast.makeText(this, "contact info : " + phn_no + "\n" + name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Log.d(TAG," " + data1.size());
                        Log.d(TAG, data1.toString());
                    }
                }
            }
    }

}
```

Contacts XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"         android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"     android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.deptofpharmacology.test.Contacts">


<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Contact"
    android:id="@+id/contact1"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="82dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="btnAddContacts_Click" />


<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Contact"
    android:id="@+id/contact2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/contact1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="btnAddContacts_Click" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Contact"
    android:id="@+id/contact3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/contact2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="49dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="btnAddContacts_Click" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Contact"
    android:id="@+id/contact4"
    android:layout_below="@+id/contact3"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="btnAddContacts_Click" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Next"
    android:id="@+id/Next1"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="btnDone_Click" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

the Database

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class DatabHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "PostalE.db";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "emergency_table";
public static final String COL_1= "ID";
public static final String COL_2 = "CONTACTS";
public static final String COL_3 = "NUMBERS";
public static final String COL_4 = "MESSAGE";

public DatabHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, CONTACTS TEXT ,NUMBERS INTEGER, MESSAGE TEXT)");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
onCreate(db);
}

public boolean insertRecord(HashMap<String, String> queryValues) {
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("name", queryValues.get("name"));
    values.put("phone", queryValues.get("phone"));
    database.insert(COL_2, null, values);
    database.insert(COL_3, null, values);
    long result = database.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,values);
    if(result == -1){
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}

/**
public boolean insertData(String name, String phone){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_2,name);
    contentValues.put(COL_3,phone);
    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);
    if(result == -1){
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}

**/
public boolean insertData(String message){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_4,message);
    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);
    if(result == -1){
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I would like to help but this question is quite vague. What would you like to do exactly?

Comment: I am trying to get my ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>  into my SQLite database android. I do not know how to do that. I have a method to take in a hash map in the database helper. But I do not know how to pass the hash map from the contact java. I do not know how to create a method to pass the hash map to a database. I have posted my code.

Answer (score 1):

This how you add it to the database from Contacts.class

```
DatabHelper databasecontroller = new DatabHelper(Contacts.this);
//or context

HashMap<String, String> values = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
values .put("somecolumnname1", sometextbuttonorwhateverview1.getText().toString());
values .put("somecolumnname2", sometextbuttonorwhateverview2.getText().toString());
values .put("somecolumnname13", sometextbuttonorwhateverview3.getText().toString());
databasecontroller.enterdata(values);
```

Put in Database

```
public void enterdata(HashMap<String, String> Vi) {
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put("somecolumnname1", Vi.get("somecolumnname1"));
    values.put("somecolumnname2", Vi.get("somecolumnname2"));
    //etc
    database.insert("DatabHelper", null, values);
    database.close();
}
```

Where you do this

```
HashMap<String, String> h = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        h.put("name", name);
                        h.put("phone", phn_no);
                        data1.add(h);
```

You can simplify by doing

```
HashMap<String, String> values = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
values .put("name", name);
values .put("phone", phn_no);
databasecontroller.enterdata(values);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I have a question though...I do not understand your first code " add it to the database". Is this code suppose to go in the method I made to pass the information to the database or is it suppose to go directly into the code? If it is suppose to go into the method, isn't the hashmap in the code you gave suppose to somehow copy the hashmap I already have somehow to get the data?

Comment: You can do that first part on any activity. That controller is just connecting your actual database.class with the current activity.

Comment: ah okay, and I also don't understand the "somecolumname" "sometextbutton~". My items are saved in an Arraylist<HashMap<String,String>> already, I don't understand what the "somecolumname" "sometextbutton~" is used for..I apologize for the newbie questions. I am extremely new at this but thank you so much for your patience and help!

Comment: Tell me how it turns out. If this is the right please remember to chose it as best answer.

Answer (score 1):

put in databaseclass

```
public void inserI(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues newValues1 = new ContentValues();

    for(int i=0;i<list1.size();i++){

    newValues1.put(ITEM, list1.get(i).get("names").toString());
    newValues1.put(QUA, list1.get(i).get("phone").toString());
    //newValues1.put(RATE,list1.get(i).get(THIRD_COLUMN).toString());

    db.insert(QUANTITY, null, newValues1);
}
```